# CDI : Is @Decorator useful in real projects compared to classic decorator pattern

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, cdi, decorator

```
Env:
   Wildfly 9.0.1
   Weld 2.2.14
```

I am currently looking into the possibilities of using CDI @Decorator in our legacy code base wherever reasonable.

Looking at the spec and the java ee 7 examples, the CDI @Decorators seems to be

- Defined at compile time. Well, at least the list of them
- Objects can not be decorated at runtime like the classic Decorator
  pattern

To quote from the classic Pizza and Toppings example, one can create top-up pizzas of any depth at runtime. For example : new Cheese(new Ham(new Pepper(new LargePizza())))

Is this possible with the CDI @Decorator ? If not, what is the real use of the @Decorator where you have to declare the objects at compile time i.e. with @Decorator and @Delegate (and list of them in beans.xml)? May be i am missing something here.

Thanks in advance,

Rakesh

Comment: One way i have used decorators is to hide expensive calls to the actual service calls by using some kind of cache. This is only when it was impossible for me to use some kind of cache interceptor logic

Answer (score 4):

You asked what CDI gives you compared to the classical, written by hand, decorator pattern. Not much. Only:

- guarantee that injected bean is already "decorated" automatically
- let you skip overriding each and every method from the decorated interface

BTW, some clarification, you said:

> With CDI (...) objects can not be decorated at runtime like the classic Decorator pattern

Wrong, objects are decorated at runtime. But *what is being decorated by what*, is declared at compile time.
If you would implement decorator pattern by yourself (classic approach), then you'll gain mentioned flexibility - but do you really need this? Sometimes yes, sometimes no.

---

UPDATE: CDI `@Decorator` indeed doesn't prevent the **class explosion** problem. This is a big drawback.

But I can imagine also a valid use case for the CDI `@Decorator` - e.g. let's say you would want to add some behaviour for the `EntityManager`. In this case you cannot go with inheritance, because JPA implementation is unknown at compile-time. If you would go with implementing decorator by hand, then you'll have to write many, many methods, see this:

```
public class CraftedEntityManager implements EntityManager {

    private final EntityManager delegator;

    public CraftedEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
        this.delegator = em;
    }

    @Override
    public void persist(Object entity) {
        delegator.persist(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T merge(T entity) {
        return delegator.merge(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(Object entity) {
        delegator.remove(entity);
    }

    // ...
    // here goes almost 50 other methods of the EntityManager

}
```

So it seems to be a good use case.

Comment: Thanks @Demecki. Thats precisely my point too. Classic decorator pattern prevents class explosion. As i understand (and like you said) this is not the case with CDI where we have to declare "what is being decorated by what". That said, i was just wondering why `@Decorator` is added in first place if its not solving 'class explosion'. By design, CDI should have it. To your other question whether we need it or not is largely driven by the task at hand.  Looking at the strides that Java EE took/taking i am bit surprised that @Decorator is a limited decorator pattern as of now.

Comment: @RakeshK.Cherukuri  You are correct. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Decorators and Alternatives are two approaches for solving similar, but not quite the same problems.  In the case of an alternative, you want to satisfy an existing bean's signature while not performing any of the behavior of the original bean.  Think of it like mocking.

Decorators and interceptors are probably more closely related.  Decorators are intended to do something before/after calling the original bean's code.  This is similar to interceptors, except interceptors expect the same interception logic applied to all method calls.  Decorators don't have that expectation.

Comment: My question is about CDI decorators in particular and their usage in the real world.

Comment: @RakeshK.Cherukuri And this answer perfectly fits to your question. You asked what CDI gives you compared to hand-crafted approach. Not much. Only guarantee that injected bean is already "decorated" automatically.